# iOS open broswer from and App and close it at some point and return to the App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, browser

I have an request but I don't know if it is possible. I need to open a browser from my App (which I know that is possible and I know how to do). Then after some browsing and navigation in the browser it will land at a page which I can control. In that moment I need to close the browser and go back to my application.

Is it possible to do that? And if can you provide me some lead how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use URLScheme in you info.plist

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899

for test you can open your app form other app also

with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourScHeme://"]];
```

Comment: I also suspected that this is the way. Only one question, using the scheme will return me to the same state of my App when I left it or not, @balkaransingh?

Comment: no it's relaunch  your app. you can open particular viewcontroller if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of opening browser from your application, you can use UIWebview to load web content so that no need to do transition from your app to browser.

Here is tuturial which may help you.
http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2013/11/17/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-revisited-part-1/

Comment: I know but my requirements are to use mobile browser. I am not aware of consideration but this is a must if it is possible.

Comment: Then in this case answer given by @balkaransingh could be option but there are two caveats to this option.

1)App has to open URL scheme from default browser, When to fire that URL programatically is question.
2)It will be relaunch of app so need to maintain app state